# child view not handling event in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a template as part of a page that looks like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="listbeer">

    <table>
    {{#each content}}
        {{#view "DHApp.BeerrowView"}}
        <tr>
            <td><button>{{name}}</button></td>
            <td>{{brewery}}</td>
        </tr>   
        {{/view}}

    {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

I also have two views, one encapsulating the table and one that encapsulates rows. When I click on the button only the parent (whole table) view click handler gets called(the one below that says parent picked up click). I can't make the child view handler be called. Any ideas why as I've tried various things and cant get anywhere?

The views code looks like so:

```
DHApp.BeerrowView = Ember.View.extend({
        click: function(evt) {
            alert("ClickableView was clicked!");
        }
    });

DHApp.ListbeerView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'listbeer',
        click: function(evt) {
            alert("parent picked up view");
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your `BeerrowView` the following way:

```
DHApp.BeerrowView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    click: function(evt) {
        alert("ClickableView was clicked!");
    }
});
```

and the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="listbeer">

    <table>
        {{#each content}}
            {{#view "DHApp.BeerrowView"}}
                <td><button>{{name}}</button></td>
                <td>{{brewery}}</td>
            {{/view}}

       {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

The reason after that is that the view adds an extra `div` if you don't define the tag name.
See [ember view guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/) for further reference..

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply that fixed it. Though I am still unclear as to why. If it's caused an additional html element why does that affect the event handler? My initial expectation would be that neither handler would work...

Comment: The click handler is attached to the view's element. The parent view wraps the whole `table` with `div` - which is valid, thus it works. The child view wraps the `tr` with `div` - this is invalid thus doesn't work.